# How to run a package that contains different public classes?

Tags: java, package

I have created a Package named `com.choice`. It contains three files:

- `ShopApp`: this is a public class which contains the main method
- `Customer`: public class
- `Clothing`: public class

I have compiled the whole package using `javac *.java`, this has compiled successfully, but when I run it I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: what command did you used to run it?

Comment: I believe some information is missing in order for someone to be able to (properly) help you: 1. how did you run your program? 2. For which class do you get the `ClassNotFoundException`? (edit your answer with that information so it's not hidden in the comments)

Comment: Tried in many ways as below - F:\ com.choice>java  ShopApp and another one - F:\com.choice>java com\choice\ShopApp

Comment: ShopApp has main method thats why i used this class for run

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this folder structure

```
E:\
 |-- Choice
     |-- com
         |-- choice
             |-- ShopApp.java
             |-- Customer.java
             |-- Clothing.java
```

Your source files should have the following package name:

```
package com.choice
```

And then you do:

```
cd E:\Choice
javac com\choice\ShopApp.java com\choice\Customer.java com\choice\Clothing.java
```

And run with

```
 cd E:\Choice
 java com.choice.ShopApp
```

Please note java names are case sensitive, so follow the conventions of NOT using capital letters in package names and their corresponding directories. In this example the directory `Choice` is a project root, and may be called whatever, it is not used by java, but it is where you execute your commands from.